# Activity diagram. Is that correct way to define multiple selection?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Is that correct way to define multiple selection?
When I want to define selections like in menu?
[image: can decision node have many outputs? like this?]

Comment: can I do it this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have any number of outgoing flows.
But note, that the label of a decision should not be an action and that each outgoing flow should have a guard condition. The common part of all guards may be used as a decision label.

[image: activity diagram]

Comment: thanks, and what about quotes around guardes, is it just an optional choice?

Comment: Yes. A guard is a boolean expression, e.g. choice = 'Save'. In this example, the first part is written in the decision symbol. The recommended expression language in UML diagrams is OCL (Object Constraint Language), but I know very little about OCL.

Comment: I still don't see much progress around in using OCL except in academic circles. Reading it is rather ok, but writing the correct OCL syntax is a pain. Unless you don't have a code generator plain text is more than enough. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add as many outgoing edges as you need: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node

Comment: You should mention that there need to be guards on each vertex since without it's random where the flow will go.